# PostgreSQL - Streaming materialized views changes

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I use PostgreSQL to store millions of rows in a materialized view that is refreshed asynchronously. The data is a source of multiple joins from multiple tables.

Is it possible to stream/notify which rows are changed (whether it's an create/update/delete) in a materialized view?

Comment: Materialized views in Postgres are only updated en masse using `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view`. You cannot perform partial updates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too low on reputation so I have to ask in answer section.

From the beginning - why do you use materialized view to storing millions of rows? Wouldn't it be better to store them in **classic table**? With that you could use **triggers** to log changes on this entity.

Comment: Updating data is outside of our reach so the whole database is being copied using AWS DMS. We then use materialized views to construct objects we care about.

Comment: You could try to create triggers if "the whole database is being copied" means, by the chance, that you're copying it to your db, then process further. But I bet it does not. 

You could also try to add some timestamp column to this materialized table to store time of added date to query after this, but I wasn't able to do it now.

Answer (score 0):

As of Postgres 9.4, you can refresh a materialized view "concurrently" to affect only the new and modified rows.

From http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-materialized-views/

> "With CONCURRENTLY option, PostgreSQL creates a temporary updated version of the materialized view, compares two versions, and **performs INSERT and UPDATE only the differences**. You can query against the materialized view while it is being updated. One requirement for using CONCURRENTLY option is that the materialized view must have a UNIQUE index. Notice that CONCURRENTLY option is only available from PosgreSQL 9.4."

Official docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html